# Removing focus does not stop auto scrolling in a RichEdit control in Delphi 11.3

Tags: scroll, delphi-11-alexandria, trichedit

I would like to add lines at the end of a RichEdit control which has more lines than can fit into the set height of the control, without these new lines being displayed on the screen.

Here is a test code that demonstrates the issue:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    AddLine: TButton;
    procedure AddLineClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RichEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AddLineClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 i : integer;
begin
 form1.RichEdit1.HideSelection := true;
 form1.RichEdit1.Clear;
 for i := 1 to 100 do
  Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add('Add New Line # ' + IntToStr(i));
 end;

procedure TForm1.RichEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
 form1.AddLine.SetFocus;
end;

end.
```

The form has a RichEdit control and a button.
The height of the RichEdit control can fit 10 lines of text.
Pressing the button sets the HideSelection property of the RichEdit control to true and adds 100 lines to the RichEdit control.
The onChange event of the RichEdit control sets focus away from the control.

In a previous version of Delphi (2005) this code would prevent auto scrolling when adding lines, however a different behaviour is seen in Delphi 11.3 – the newly added lines are continuously displayed on the screen.

Any suggestions on how to prevent auto scrolling in Delphi 11.3 will be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your help,

Leonid

Comment: If you don't want the RichEdit to ever gain input focus, then why not simply disable it? Or put it on a Panel and disable the Panel instead.

Comment: Thank you Remy, but this will not solve my problem. Although the input is only from the running program, the user needs to use the vertical scroll bar to be able to see the earlier input, while lines are added at the bottom. In the actual application written in Delphi 2005 I had a button on the form that changed the HideSelection property, thus allowing the user to either see the newly added lines (false) or to inspect the earlier input (true). Any discussion I could find on this dates pre-2003, and the solutions match my code. Something must have changed, but I cannot find what it is.

Comment: The way you are using the `OnChange` event is very odd, there are better ways to handle that, as I mentioned earlier. I never said it would solve your issue. But in any case, "*Something must have changed, but I cannot find what it is*" - for starters, in Delphi 11.0 Embarcadero changed the version of the Win32 RichEdit control that `TRichEdit` uses: [TRichEdit Component updated to RichEdit 4.1](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#TRichEdit_Component_updated_to_RichEdit_4.1_.28MSFTEDIT.dll.29) So this could very well be a behavioral change on Microsoft's part.

Comment: If you don't want the `TRichEdit` to scroll while updating it, have you tried saving the `SelStart` and `SelLength` property values before updating and then restore them afterwards? Also, you should be wrapping your `Lines.Add()` loop with `Lines.BeginUpdate()`/`Lines.EndUpdate()`, too. Worst case, you could just save the `TRichEdit`'s scrollbar position and then restore it. Either way, you should not be relying on `HideSelection` to control scrolling behavior, that is not its job and never was.

Comment: I can return to the same part of the  content of the component after a new line is added, however no matter what I do, including all of your suggestions, the displayed text first jumps to the end when a new line is added, and then returns to where it was before a new line was added. Hopefully there is a different control I can use that supports the required behaviour